# Trying to get multiple formulas in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

How do I combine two formulas in one cell? Given three values, I need to perform a calculation as follows:  (Max-Min) / Median

I have

`=MAX(U33,U35,U43)-MIN(U33,U35,U43)`

and

`=Y40/MEDIAN(U33,U35,U43)`

`Y40` is the Max-Min.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Parentheses in Excel formulas work just like in math equations. Instead of using the `Y40` step, just enclose the first calculation in parens then apply the second. `=(MAX(U33,U35,U43)-MIN(U33,U35,U43))/MEDIAN(U33,U35,U43)`

Comment: It seems fine to me. Let's re open.